# Datos null de c# a acces

Tags: c#, ms-access, crud

Hola comunidad tengo una duda, me encuentro haciendo un pequeño ejercicio para practicar
c# con conexión a acces en visual studio y me pregunto como insertar datos null o Ceros en una tabla de acces
en el caso de que varios texbox queden en blanco al momento de insertar ya que al final quiero hacer una suma con los
valores que se hallan ingresado en este caso R1= C1+C2+C3+C4 que son de tipo int, ya que no quiero utilizar strings
y conversiones porque me generaria errores de tipos de datos, espero puedan sugerirme una idea. he utilizado caracteres como ? o datos nullable
pero tal vez lo he echo mal.

En general lo que pretendo es aprender como ingresar datos null de una caja de textoa de c# a campos de acces para realizar operaciones
como sumas, restas, multiplicacion y divison sin que los campos vacios o nulos generen un error.

```
class ALUMNO
    {
        public int Id  { get; set;}
        
        public string CLABE { get; set; }
        public string NOMBRE { get; set; }
       public Nullable<int> C1 { get; set; }
        // public int C1 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> C2 { get; set; }
        //public int C2 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> C3 { get; set; }
        //public int C3 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> C4 { get; set; }
        //public int C4 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> R1 { get; set; }
        //public int R1 { get; set; }
}
```

En el CRUD

```
public string Insertar(ALUMNO p)
        {

          //  string per = p.Periodo;
            string res = "";

            if (p.Periodo == "1° PARCIAL")
            {
              
                string comando = string.Format
                ("insert into TablaAlumnos " +
                "(CLABE, NOMBRE, C1, C2, C3, C4, R1, H1, H2, H3, H4, R2, ACTYVAL1, ACTYVAL2, ACTYVAL3,ACTYVAL4, R3, DES1, DES2, DES3, DES4, R4, SUMA, COMP_ADQ, INA) " +
                " values ('{0}','{1}',{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11},{12},{13},{14},{15},{16},{17},{18},{19},{20},{21},{22},'{23}',{24})",
                p.CLABE, p.NOMBRE, p.C1, p.C2, p.C3, p.C4, p.R1, p.H1, p.H2, p.H3, p.H4, p.R2, p.ACTYVAL1, p.ACTYVAL2, p.ACTYVAL3, p.ACTYVAL4, p.R3, p.DES1, p.DES2, p.DES3, p.DES4, p.R4, p.SUMA, p.COMP_ADQ, p.INA);
                OleDbCommand cmd =
            new OleDbCommand(comando, cn);
                try
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                        res = "registro exitoso";
                    else
                        res = "No se pudo obtener conexión";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    res = ex.Message;
                }
                finally
                {
                    cn.Close();
                }
```

Evento del boton

```
try
            {
                
                ALUMNO p = new ALUMNO();

                p.CLABE = txtClabe.Text;
                p.NOMBRE = txtNombre.Text;

                p.C1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtCon1.Text);
                p.C2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtCon2.Text);
                p.C3 = Convert.ToInt32(txtCon3.Text);
                p.C4 = Convert.ToInt32(txtCon4.Text);
                p.R1 = Convert.ToInt32(p.C1 + p.C2 + p.C3 + p.C4);


 p.Periodo = cbPeriodo.Text; ;
                    MessageBox.Show(crud.Insertar(p));
                    llenargrid();

                    Thread.Sleep(20);
                    txtClabe.Clear();
                    txtNombre.Clear();
                    txtCon1.Clear();
                    txtCon2.Clear();
                    txtCon3.Clear();
                    txtCon4.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Hola, podrias darle un voto a las respuestas que te sirvieron y aceptar la que te fue mas util, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que estás buscando es el tipo de dato [DBNull](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.dbnull.value?view=net-5.0)
Es el que se usa para asignar valores NULL a un campo de una tabla en las bases de datos.
Por ejemlo:

```
new SqlParameter("@Price", items.Price == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)items.Price)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pues podrías hacer esto:

```
ALUMNO p = new ALUMNO();
p.CLABE = txtClabe.Text;
p.NOMBRE = txtNombre.Text;

p.C1 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCon1.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtCon1.Text) : 0;
p.C2 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCon2.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtCon2.Text) : 0;
p.C3 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCon3.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtCon3.Text) : 0;
p.C4 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCon4.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtCon4.Text) : 0;
p.R1 = p.C1 + p.C2 + p.C3 + p.C4;
```

La **función IsNullOrWhiteSpace** recibe como parámetro un **string** y retorna **true** si ese **string** está vacío o solamente está llenado con espacios. Si no está vacío retorna **false**.

Se utiliza además el **operador ternario ? :**, el cual funciona como un **condicional if-else**, ejemplo:

```
if(condición)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Usar este **operador ternario** nos hace el código más legible.

Pues bien, explicado esto lo que se hace en el código es preguntar si cada **TextBox** que nos interesa no está vacío, si no está vacío entonces se guarda en el **objeto ALUMNO** el número que escribimos en este **TextBox**, si está vacío, el valor de esa propiedad del **objeto Alumno** toma el valor **0**. Después se hace la suma y ya.